# Changing Tax to GST within WordPress/WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[image: Changing Tax to GST]

I am having trouble changing the wording within my cart page on my website. As my shop is in Australia I want to change the naming convention from Tax to GST. I have changed the language file (/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages/woocommerce.pot) but it hasn't affected my shop at all.

Does anyone have another way of changing the wording within the cart page? Are there any PHP files I can edit within /wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/?

Answer (score 12):

There are filters available for this. Include them in your theme's functions.php file:

**/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_inc_tax_or_vat', function () {
  return __( '(incl. GST)', 'woocommerce' );
});
```

<sub>WooCommerce 2.3.8, PHP 5.3+</sub>

See also: `woocommerce_countries_tax_or_vat` & `woocommerce_countries_ex_tax_or_vat`

Filters and actions are used for modifying and extending core functionality (without editing anything that might be overridden by an update).

Check out the [WooCommerce docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/). They go to town with this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Display tax totals as a single total

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_tax_or_vat', function () {
  return __( 'GST', 'woocommerce' );
});
```

Another Examples

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_inc_tax_or_vat', function () {
  return __( 'GST', 'woocommerce' );
});

add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_ex_tax_or_vat', function () {
  return __( 'GST', 'woocommerce' );
});
```

Comment: How is your answer different than what is given by @som, 2 years before you.

Comment: this is wrong. The inc one should say `incl. GST` and the ex one `ex. GST`

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the same problem sovled:

The file to amend is at "includes > class-wc-countries.php"

Comment: Directly overriding plugin files is bad practice; among other things any future updates to the plugin may override your changes. Most plugins, including WooCommerce, provide hooks to allow you to safely amend/override output.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace “Includes $xx.xx Tax” in WooCommerce Cart and checkout page**

Include the following code in your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'woo_rename_tax_inc_cart', 10, 1 );

function woo_rename_tax_inc_cart( $value ) {
    $value = str_ireplace( 'Tax', 'GST', $value );
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: There are better built-in hooks to use than this. The `Tax` is displayed all throughout woocommerce.