# How can I change tax name from VAT to GST in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on one of the WordPress website and using woodmart theme. On the cart page it's showing "Includes Rs.xyz VAT" but I want it to be GST. So, how can I do that?

[image]

I haven't tried anything for this problem. So, I don't have any idea about it.

Comment: Hope [this](https://www.websitebuilderinsider.com/how-do-i-change-vat-to-gst-in-woocommerce/) helps..

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use the Loco Translate plugin to change that text.

https://xtemos.com/docs-topic/translate-woodmart-theme-with-loco-translate/

Navigate to Loco -> Plugins -> WooCommerce and search for an appropriate text.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in your current theme's **functions.php** file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_inc_tax_or_vat', function () {
  return __( '(incl. GST)', 'woocommerce' );
});
```

You see this post here [Changing Tax to GST within WordPress/WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870794/changing-tax-to-gst-within-wordpress-woocommerce)